# How to set up a if statement to change variables

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change a variable in a javascript to a default if there is no value available

```
// Parse the URL
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

// Give the URL parameters variable names
var source = 'organic';
var medium = 'organic';
var campaign = 'organic';

// Give the URL parameters variable names
var source = getParameterByName('utm_source');
var medium = getParameterByName('utm_medium');
var campaign = getParameterByName('utm_campaign');
```

I am using some javascript to pass utm variable from the url through a pardot form. I am wanting to set the default to organic as the value and then change the variable to one provided in the url if it is available

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What goes wrong? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: I don't understand the point of the first line inside `getParameterByName`.  That regex doesn't appear to match any of the parameter values you're passing into the method.  That line doesn't appear to do anything useful, or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: so i grab utm variable from the url string really what i want to do is the following I can write it in php but just don't know how to do it in javascript $source="Organic"; if (isset(getParameterByName('utm_source')) { $source=getParameterByName('utm_source'); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the default as a parameter to the function, and return that in your conditional operator instead of `""`:

```
function getParameterByName(name, default) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? default : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

// Give the URL parameters variable names
var source = 'organic';
var medium = 'organic';
var campaign = 'organic';

// Give the URL parameters variable names
var source = getParameterByName('utm_source', source);
var medium = getParameterByName('utm_medium', medium);
var campaign = getParameterByName('utm_campaign', campaign);
```

Another option would be to use the `||` operator to apply a default in the assignment:

```
/ Give the URL parameters variable names
var source = 'organic';
var medium = 'organic';
var campaign = 'organic';

// Give the URL parameters variable names
var source = getParameterByName('utm_source') || source;
var medium = getParameterByName('utm_medium') || medium;
var campaign = getParameterByName('utm_campaign') || campaign;
```